# Как убрать заголовок Activity из содержимого вкладок TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

Создаю TabHost с двумя вкладками. Содержимое вкладок храню в отдельных Activity. В итоге заголовок попадает внутрь вкладки (см. рисунок). `equestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` у "внутренних" Actuivity не помогает.

[image: Вид TabHost c двумя вкладками]

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Создаем и инициализируем TabHost
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 1");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(tabHost.getContext(), One.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка 2");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(tabHost.getContext(), Two.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tabintent.MainActivity">    
        <TabHost
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код вложенных Activity стандартный.

Comment: используйте для вложенных активити тему без ActionBar

Comment: Да, действительно, все работает. Если в `styles.xml` прописать `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Есть еще один вариант. Создавать содержимое вкладки используя LayoutInflater. В этом случае создаем xml файл с содержимым, указываем реализацию интерфейса TabContentFactory:  `tabSpec.setContent(myTabContentFactory)`, далее создаем содержимое из xml в методе `createTabContent` примерно так: return `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item1, null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы убрать заголовки активити во вкладках,используйте тему без `ActionBar`, например:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```